# A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Making a function call to .NET 4 to native code is resulting in the following exception:

> A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Here is my definition in Native Code:

```
typedef void ( CALLBACK* CB_DOWNLOADING )
(
      ULONG,    // secs elapsed
      LPARAM,   // custom callback param
      LPBOOL    // abort?
);


FETCH_API HttpFetchW
(
      LPCWSTR         url,
      IStream**       retval,
      LPCWSTR         usrname  = NULL,
      LPCWSTR         pwd      = NULL,
      BOOL            unzip    = TRUE,
      CB_DOWNLOADING  cb       = NULL,
      LPARAM          cb_param = 0,
      LPWSTR          ctype    = NULL,
      ULONG           ctypelen = 0
);
```

Here is the .NET counterpart:

```
[DllImport(dllPath, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention =     CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern FETCH HttpFetchW
        (
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            string url,
            out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream retval,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            string usrname,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            string pwd,
            bool unzip,
            dlgDownloadingCB cb,
            IntPtr cb_param,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            string ctype,
            ulong ctypelen
        );
```

Where FETCH is an enum.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal delegate void dlgDownloadingCB(ulong elapsedSec, IntPtr lParam, bool abort);


internal static void DownloadingCB(ulong elapsedSec, IntPtr lParam, bool abort)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("elapsedSec = " + elapsedSec.ToString());
        }
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative within the .NET 4?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think `LPBOOL` matches `ref bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only clear error in `HttpFetchW` that I can see is that C# `ulong` is 64 bits wide, by C++ `ULONG` is 32 bits wide. The C# code for the final parameter should be `uint`.

Other things to check include the calling convention. Are you sure it is `cdecl`? Are you sure that `SetLastError` should be `true`?

As for the callback, you make the same error with `ulong`. And the `abort` parameter is `LPBOOL`. That is a pointer to `BOOL`. So you should declare the C# parameter as a `ref` parameter. And the callback is declared with `CALLBACK` which is `stdcall`.

So the delegate should be:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal delegate void dlgDownloadingCB(
    uint elapsedSec, 
    IntPtr lParam, 
    ref bool abort
);
```

Or simply delete the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute since the default is `stdcall`.

I think it exceptionally likely that since the callback is `stdcall`, so will the function. I expect that the `FETCH_API` macro expands to both the return enum and the calling convention. Since you did not supply those details, I can only guess. You'll need to check.

The other thing that we cannot check is `CB_DOWNLOADING`.

Anyway, with those assumptions, the function becomes:

```
[DllImport(dllPath, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern FETCH HttpFetchW(
    string url,
    out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream retval,
    string usrname,
    string pwd,
    bool unzip,
    dlgDownloadingCB cb,
    IntPtr cb_param,
    string ctype,
    uint ctypelen
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Source : MSDN

> In the .NET Framework version 3.5, the pInvokeStackImbalance MDA is disabled by default. When you use the .NET Framework version 3.5 with Visual Studio 2005, the pInvokeStackImbalance MDA will appear in the Managed Debugging Assistants list in the Exceptions dialog box (which is displayed when you click Exceptions on the Debug menu). However, selecting or clearing the Thrown check box for pInvokeStackImbalance does not enable or disable the MDA; it only controls whether Visual Studio throws an exception when the MDA is activated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0htdy0k3(v=vs.110).aspx